# service application that monitor files being downloaded

Tags: c#, vb.net

Need to create a service application that monitor all files being downloaded. I was thinking about using the file watcher class but some end users can change the download directory. Any idea would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitoring file system is no indicative of download activity, as you already figured out. Browsers do not expose a cross-platform API to report download events. Browsers plugins do, but that requires the plugin to be loaded, enabled and you'll need separate plugins for each browser out there. So the only sensible approach is a [filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In fact the OS exposes a handy helper layer specifically designed for this, the [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Of course, C++ and networking expertise is required. Detecting downloads from all traffic is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: +1. Note that if you are looking for practical solution than forcing all traffic to go through proxy/gateway is easier and more traditional solution, but not acceptable for SO (more like http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using C#? Is there a dll that can be imported?

Comment: You need at least a core system driver which must be C++. There are examples of system drivers that delegate the logic to C# eg http://www.easefilter.com/programming.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor files downloaded on computers in an office environment, your best bet would be to install a proxy server.